# Python3 Socket / Selector register more than one event

Tags: python, sockets, selector

I have always been using blocking/synchronous sockets so far since I have realised non-blocking/asynchronous sockets can be more powerful when you are doing IO.

So, to start off I decided to make a simple project creating a non-blocking socket able to read and write when the events are set, so I basically register the events in the selector and then enter in a endless loop waiting for the events, when the events are set I callback them.

```
import socket
import selectors

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.setblocking(False)
selector = selectors.DefaultSelector()

def write():
    print('Able to Write')
    sock.send(b'Hello')
    #I don't want to keep sending data, so I don't re-register the event

def read():
    print('Able to Read')
    data = sock.recv(1024).decode()
    selector.register(sock.fileno(), selectors.EVENT_READ, read) 
    # I register the event again because I'd like to keep reading from the socket.

# I don't use events here...
try:
    sock.connect(('localhost', 80))
except BlockingIOError:
    pass

# I register read and write events with their respective callbacks. Error is raised...
selector.register(sock.fileno(), selectors.EVENT_READ, read)
selector.register(sock.fileno(), selectors.EVENT_WRITE, write)

while True:
    events = selector.select()
    for key, _ in events:
        callback = key.data
        callback()
        selector.unregister(key.fileobj)
        #Unregister the event
```

Here is my code.
My goal is to be able to read and write asynchronously, so my idea is to register many read and write events on the same socket.

Answer (score 0):

You must register all events at the same time.

`selector.register(sock.fileno(), selectors.EVENT_WRITE | selectors.EVENT_READ, write)`

That uses a bitwise OR. Note that you'll run into the same problem in read(), since you haven't unregistered the FD before invoking the callback.